# SIGABRT Error - Exactly after 3rd Run (both iPhone & iPad Simulators)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sigabrt

My app loads and runs fine in both the iPhone and iPad simulators (5.0, 5.1, 6.0, 6.1). On the the 3rd attempt "EXACTLY" I receive a SIGABRT error with a "(lldb)" log output.  Here's the output from a bt (Back Trace) command:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x98960a6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, stop           reason = signal SIGABRT
frame #0: 0x98960a6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
frame #1: 0x96d87b2f libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_kill + 101
frame #2: 0x0209b57b libsystem_sim_c.dylib`abort + 140
frame #3: 0x02aa5b4e GraphicsServices`GSRegisterPurpleNamedPort + 348
frame #4: 0x02aa569f GraphicsServices`_GSEventInitialize + 123
frame #5: 0x02aa5c1f GraphicsServices`GSEventInitialize + 36
frame #6: 0x00a153f9 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 600
frame #7: 0x00002d8d AppName`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff3bc) + 141 at main.m:16
frame #8: 0x00002cb5 AppName`start + 53
```

I've also performed the following without resolution to produce definitive information to help me track down the source of the error:

- Added global Exception Breakpoint
- Try Catch to NSLog from main
- Tried every "Diagnostic" by editing the project schema and replicating the error with additional (Memory Management, Logging and Debugger) settings enabled.
- Slow down the frequency I Start/Stop the app
- Closed XCode
- Rebooted

I have not done:
- Run the app on a physical device (still waiting on Apple to confirm my corp acct)

Answer (score 3):

Per the following article

http://www.tuaw.com/2013/06/05/devjuice-10-8-4-and-the-ios-simulator

This appears to have resolved my issue:

Update your scheme by selecting Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme, and choose the GDB debugger for your debug scheme from the Info Tab.

The default was: LLDB