# only (lldb) output in debug area, no other message

Tags: ios, xcode

I got a rare problem that randomly when I ran my app in xcode, the simulator will stop and in the debug area only "(lldb)" is shown. It is random because when I ran again without modifying my code, it will run. What could have been the problem? I tried it in my other projects but still the same. Thank you.

xcode 4.6.2
Mountain Lion 10.8.4 (lldb error starts after updating 10.8.4 from 10.8.3, I don't know if this has some impact on xcode)

## update1 - result from Douglas

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x94f06a6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
frame #0: 0x94f06a6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
frame #1: 0x907b1b2f libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_kill + 101
frame #2: 0x018db57b libsystem_sim_c.dylib`abort + 140
frame #3: 0x01f45b4e GraphicsServices`GSRegisterPurpleNamedPort + 348
frame #4: 0x01f4569f GraphicsServices`_GSEventInitialize + 123
frame #5: 0x01f45c1f GraphicsServices`GSEventInitialize + 36
frame #6: 0x0027ed99 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 600
frame #7: 0x00001ccd sampleapp`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff3a0) + 141 at main.m:16
```

Comment: Does Matthias' answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999127/lldb-run-time-error-on-xcode) solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks @HAS it solved my problem. As for now, no crashes occur.

Comment: Yeah, this is just a temporary solution. I suggest you [file a bug](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbugreport.apple.com%2Fcgi-bin%2FWebObjects%2FRadarWeb.woa%2Fwa%2FsignIn&ei=I0ezUYjXGM764QSdoIHYCg&usg=AFQjCNGKeBqNsxno9hHhcP_MegHK_zQM2Q) (if no one else has done yet).

Comment: According to [this](http://m.tuaw.com/2013/06/05/devjuice-10-8-4-and-the-ios-simulator/) no more radars are necessary. An alternative to changing the debugger is killing your app, waiting a few seconds and then rerunning it.

Comment: Thanks. It is clear now that the OS update has something to do with it.

Answer (score 20):

In the debug area, after you see the lldb, type in bt, this will show you the crash log.  Hopefully this will give you some insight as to what caused the crash/stop.

Comment: Thanks. I've udpated my question, I perform your suggestion but the error log is still vague upon my understanding.

Comment: Glad to see that I got you rolling in the right direction!  Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I just posted the same question and seemed to have fixed my own issue:

[SIGABRT Error - Exactly after 3rd Run (both iPhone & iPad Simulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994251/sigabrt-error-exactly-after-3rd-run-both-iphone-ipad-simulators/17002391#17002391)

---

This appears to have resolved my issue:

Update your scheme by selecting Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme, and choose the GDB debugger for your debug scheme from the Info Tab.

The default was: LLDB

Be aware of the 2 debuggers: [GDB Vs LLDB debuggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707883/gdb-vs-lldb-debuggers)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same output with only "(lldb)" being displayed. I *could* re-create the app crashing, though I couldn't really see why the certain steps should cause the app to crash? However, (from my initial tests) I am unable to crash the app running on an actual phone, which suggests to me something is dodgy with the simulator.

Xcode 7/7.2.1
iPhone 5S running iOS 9.2.1

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into a similar issue, it was because I somehow accidentally set a breakpoint on a line of code. Just click on the blue ribbon on the line of code to unset it.