# (lldb) Run time Error on Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have this code and it is not working for me and creating a runtime error

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
//position button
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50);
[myButton setTitle:@"\u2606" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// add targets and actions
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// add to a view
[self.view addSubview:myButton];

}

-(void)myButtonClicked{
[myButton setTitle:@"\u2605" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I got this from this website and cannot find a way to remove this runtime error. Thanks

Comment: can you explain, why you dont post the output of the runtime error?

Comment: the output of the runtime error is only "(lldb) " nothing else. thanks

Comment: another thing that i found out is that it is only happening on the iOS simulator. On my device this is not an issue

Comment: type bt in lldb and post that backtrace info here

Comment: “(lldb)” is LLDB's prompt; it doesn't describe the crash at all. Typing `bt` will at least get you the stack trace (“backtrace”) of what your program was doing when it occurred.

Comment: since this was fixed in Xcode 4.6.3 I'm voting for "too localized"

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much guessing, but I did experience the same problem.

It might be coincidence, but for me this problem appeared the first time after I updates OS X to 10.8.4. Since then every other Run ends in a crash.

The backtrace for my case looks like this:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x9573da6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
frame #0: 0x9573da6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
frame #1: 0x9476ab2f libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_kill + 101
frame #2: 0x024e857b libsystem_sim_c.dylib`abort + 140
frame #3: 0x026afb4e GraphicsServices`GSRegisterPurpleNamedPort + 348
frame #4: 0x026af69f GraphicsServices`_GSEventInitialize + 123
frame #5: 0x026afc1f GraphicsServices`GSEventInitialize + 36
frame #6: 0x0076ed99 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 600
frame #7: 0x0000225d XXX 3`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff36c) + 141 at main.m:16
frame #8: 0x00002185 XXX 3`start + 53
```

Since it works perfectly fine 50% of all launches, and it worked the months before I did the update, and it works with gdb, I'm pretty sure this is a bug on Apples side.

A workaround for this problem might be to switch from lldb to gdb. It worked for me.

You do this in the scheme editor (press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>). Change the debugger to gdb in the Run scheme.

[image]

Since this is like the third question (others were closed already) or so that I saw on stackoverflow in the few days since 10.8.4 was released I'm pretty sure this behaviour is related to the update.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked :D I think Apple will fix it in the next updates (hope so)

Comment: Xcode 4.6.3 (available since yesterday) fixes that bug. LLDB works fine again.