# (lldb) Error in xcode 5 ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, lldb

I am building an app following this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xyKZixvSd0

I have no errors or warnings in my xcode project but when I try to run the project and click on the screen (It is supposed to get rid of the labels and start the game if you check out the code) the simulator keeps ending and the error on the bottom of the screen appears '(lldb)' I am not sure what this means or how to fix is to any help is greatly appreciated! I included the source code below:

Here is my following source code in my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int Y;
BOOL Start;

@interface SimpleTableViewController : UIViewController

{

IBOutlet UILabel  *Intro1;
IBOutlet UILabel  *Intro2;
IBOutlet UILabel  *Intro3;

IBOutlet UIImageView *Bird;

NSTimer *timer;

}

-(void)BirdMove;

@end
```

Here is my source code for my .m file:

```
#import "SimpleTableViewController.h"

@implementation SimpleTableViewController

-(void)BirdMove{
    Bird.center = CGPointMake(Bird.center.x, Bird.center.y + Y);
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (Start)
    {
        Intro1.hidden = YES;
        Intro2.hidden = YES;
        Intro3.hidden = YES;

        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(BirdMove) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        Start = NO;
    }

    Y = -7;
    Bird.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"birdup.png"];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    Y = 7;
    Bird.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"birddown.png"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    Start = YES;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated since I am new to xcode and programming!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999127/lldb-run-time-error-on-xcode and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983192/weird-error-message-in-xcode-4-3-with-lldb

Comment: can you give the error message? lldb is only the debugger console. There must be more that that.

Comment: Where would I find more to the error message? Sorry I am new to Xcode.